# Is it possible to have the dock in different positions in different desktop?

Tags: high-sierra, dock, desktop, settings

Is it possible to have the dock in different positions in different desktops? In particular I'd like to change the settings between a normal desktop and a desktop where there's an app at full screen. In this way I'd keep the dock in lower side of the desktop when there's an app at full screen and vertically on the left side during normal use.

I have this problem that, sicne I usually have the dock vertically on the left, it pops out everytime i go to the far left in an app I'm using with full screen, and using this app I have to move the mouse to the left quite often.

Comment: As there is only one occurrence of the **Dock** process and its `orientation` _key_, I'd say **no**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No that is not possible. The dock location is set on the System Preferences/Dock pane. I tried setting it different for different spaces but all spaces (desktops) used the same setting.